# create new list with sequential names in python

Tags: python, list, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to sort a big list into sublists of similar features. I would like to create these sublist within my loop. Each item inside my list is a single row dataframe.

```
for i in len(biglist): 
    if biglist[i+1][feature]== biglist[i][feature]: 
        sublist1.append(biglist[i]) 
else:
    sublist2.append(biglist[i])
```

How could I create these sublists in an automated way? Is there an easier way knowing that items are single row dataframes with different length?

Cheers,

Comment: Your indentation is ambiguous here.  Please update your post by placing your code in a code block.

Comment: If the elements of biglist are dataframes, then `[feature]` will select a column, the `==` will give you a boolean series, and you can't branch on a boolean series.  You'll get an ambiguous-truth-value exception.

Comment: Also, in the level of your method/algorithm, how would you define `similar`, is it equals to `==`? If the items in `biglist` have a "similarity" list of `[1, 100, 1, 100, 1000]`, you won't be able to get the result by using two sublists and comparing only the adjacent `biglist` items.